# How to extract specific emails from Exchange Online using PowerShell and move or sort them?

Tags: exchange, powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

In Exchange Online (Office 365),
I need to extract emails,
from particular sending addresses,
from a handful of user mailboxes,
to another user mailbox folder.

[I've been reading about the `Export-Mailbox` PowerShell cmdlet](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/exchange/goodbye-exchange-exmerge,-hello-export-mailbox/), which seems to be able to do what I want, but I am not sure if it is possible to use on Office 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Export-Mailbox` or `New-MailboxExportRequest` cmdlets on Exchange Online,

The only way is Exporting it from Outlook client and use a Date Filter to extract the specific date range you want.

### Update:

You can use the Compliance Center in the Office 365 Admin Center to search and export content with filter options etc.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right that `Export-Mailbox` cannot be used, but exporting from the client will take too long and I don't think it is the only way.  I will investigate `Search-Mailbox`  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: search-mailbox can help to copy mails between mailboxes in the same organization. if that's what you need, you need to provide source mailbox, filter criteria and then target mailbox to copy the mail to, good luck

Comment: @Avshalom You're on point here, and the process kinda sucks for doing what the OP wants.

Comment: What about this?  https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Search-for-and-delete-email-messages-in-your-Office-365-organization-Admin-Help-3526fd06-b45f-445b-aed4-5ebd37b3762a

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @avshalom there are a couple more solution I can think of.

If you have E3 (or Exchange Plan 2) you can leverage eDiscovery.  You can create rules to meet the above requirement and copy these to a eDiscovery mailbox and/or export to PST.

Now - if you want to get creative, you may be able to leverage something like IFTT or Zappier to handle interaction over O365 API's. I've had not looked at how granular these rules can be set (per date range, etc).

Comment: I think this is new, but couldn't this method be used?  https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Search-for-and-delete-email-messages-in-your-Office-365-organization-Admin-Help-3526fd06-b45f-445b-aed4-5ebd37b3762a